# Map nested objects in React that are parsed with Axios

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I can't figure out how to iterate through multiple nested objects to .map them.

JSON currently looks like:

```
 "results": [
    {
        "cars": [
            {
                "brand": "BMW",
                "model": "430i",
                "is_onsale": false
            },
            {
                "brand": "BMW",
                "model": "540i",
                "is_onsale": true

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm using axios to get the data from URL and I'm trying to show it in console:

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://randomapi.com/api/****')
    .then(json => json.data.results.map(result => ({
        brand: result.cars.brand,
        model: result.cars.model,
        status: result.cars.is_onsale
      })))
      .then(newData => console.log(newData));
}
```

Which then returns undefined on all values.

When I change to .cars[x] then I can get the values for that specific array index:

```
brand: result.cars[0].brand,
model: result.cars[0].model,
status: result.cars[0].is_onsale
```

How can I iterate through all and store them, a simple for loop doesn't seem to go with ".then" and returns an error.

Comment: Each entry in `results` has its **own** array of `cars`. That's why `result.cars.brand` is `undefined` (the array doesn't have a property called `brand`). What do you want to do with them? Do you want to combine all of the individual results' `cars` arrays into a single array? Presumably they're separate arrays in the result for a reason...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'd like to store them to cars: [] & store: [] using:
     
     .then(newData => this.setState({cars: newData, store: newData})) 
     
so when the list is called all items in that cars array would show.

Comment: So you want to combine all the distinct `cars` arrays into one big `cars` array? Again, presumably they're on separate results for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results` is an array. Each entry in the array has its **own** array of `cars`.

From your answer in the comments under the question, it sounds like you want to combine all of those `cars` arrays into a single array, despite the fact they're separate arrays in the results (presumably for a reason). If so, you can loop through the results and add the entries from each result's `cars` array into a single, combined `cars` array. For instance:

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://randomapi.com/api/****')
    .then(json => {
        const cars = [];
        json.data.results.forEach(result => {
            cars.push(...result.cars);
        });
        return cars;
    })
    .then(allCars => {
        // do something with all the cars
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // do something with the error (report it, etc.)
    });
}
```

Or, like nearly all array operations, you can shoehorn this into  `reduce`, but it's not very clear and generates a lot of unnecessary temporary arrays:

```
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('https://randomapi.com/api/****')
    .then(json => json.data.results.reduce((all, result) => all.concat(result.cars), []))
    .then(allCars => {
        // do something with all the cars
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // do something with the error (report it, etc.)
    });
}
```